# JQM json request won't parse on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a mobile app that uses json to retrieve database data. Using my mac browser I can get the requested data and the alert and display it on a new mobile page. I can't get it to work on safari on ipad or iPhone. The page loads but no data.

Any hints would be appreciated.

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <title>tourmap_main.jpg</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>   
<script src="js/treedetails14.js"></script><div data-role="page" id="firstpage" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Winter Hill Garden Tour</h1>

</div>
<div data-role="content" id="mainpage" data-theme="a">
    <div id="area1Button"><a href="#area1" data-role="button" data-   transition="flip">AREA 1</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed"></div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="area1" data-add-back-btn="true" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Garden Tour - Area 1</h1>

</div>
<div id="area1content" data-role="content">
    <div id="tree105" class="treebutton"><a href="#detailsPage" data-rel="page" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-id="27" class="treelink">Button 1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tree106" class="treebutton"><a href="#detailsPage" data-rel="page" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-id="32" class="treelink">Button 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="detailsPage" data-overlay-theme="a">
<div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <h1 align="left"><span>Tree information -</span> <span id="treetitle"></span></h1>
</div>
<div id="treeDetails" data-role="content">
    <div id="treedescription"></div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed"></div>
</div>
```

And my script:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#firstpage', function(){ 
$('.treelink').live('click', function(){
    var serviceURL = "http://winterhill.com.au/gardentour/services/";
    currentId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'gettree.php?id='+currentId, function(data) {
        var tree = data.item;
        alert(tree.tree_description);
        $('#detailsPage').append("<p>item1="+tree.tree_description +"</p>");
    });
});
});
```

Here's the basic code setup:
http://jsfiddle.net/VgxnQ/1/

Comment: It's not that it can't parse, it's that it can't request it. Ajax requests are limited by the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) and the service doesn't offer CORS exceptions (at least, not for jsFiddles). If the service supports JSONP, that can be used cross-origin. You can read up on using JSONP with jQuery [in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp).

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code:

$('#area1').on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
    $('.treelink').on('click', function () {

        currentId = $(this).attr("data-id");

        window.sessionStorage.setItem("IdKey", currentId);

        $.mobile.changePage( "#detailsPage", 
                             { reverse: false, 
                               changeHash: false 
                             });    

    });
});

$('#detailsPage').on('pagebeforeshow', function () {

    currentId = window.sessionStorage.getItem("IdKey");

     var serviceURL = "http://winterhill.com.au/gardentour/services/";

    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'gettree.php?id=' + currentId, function (data) {
            var tree = data.item;     
            $('#treedescription').text(tree.tree_description);
        });

});
```

Still there is Access allow origin issue that needs to be resolved at the server level either have it JSONP enabled or enable the setting that it allows any domain that access the web service.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. That code snippet works but, as you suggest, not on jsFiddle or the iPad. I'm not sure I totally understand the same-origin policy in relation to my app. My php file resides on the same domain as everything else - why does it work from my Mac Browser but not the ipad (using the same internet connection)? I assume I need a better way of accessing the query result from my php file - using jsonp?

Comment: yeah try jsonp, but you should be able to access via ipad too if you are using mac wifi.